# Meaning of "I had just finished year 10 and summer break had begun"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, ambiguity

> I had just finished year 10 and summer break had begun.

What's the meaning of that year 10? Does it mean his age is 10? Or does it mean it's his tenth year of his school?

Answer (score 2):

[**Year 10**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_Ten) refers to the tenth year of school after [reception](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reception_%28School%29) in England and some other Commonwealth countries. It is roughly equivalent to [**grade 10**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grade_10) in Canada and [**10th grade**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tenth_grade) in the USA, the tenth year of school after [kindergarten](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kindergarten). The equivalence isn't exact because the English and American curricula differ in length.

Answer (score 0):

In the UK children start school at age 5. The first six years are spent at 'Primary School'. They are known as Year 1 to Year 6. 'Secondary School' (an overall term which covers names like High School, Comprehensive School, Grammar School etc) starts with Year 7 at age 11. **So by the start of Year 10, a child will typically be around 14.** At the end of Year 11 the first series of public examinations take place which until recently were known as GCSE (General Certificate in Secondary Education).

The two remaining years in Secondary school, Years 12 and 13, are what used to be known as 'The Sixth Form' and are still sometimes called that. Sometimes youngsters spend those two years at the same secondary school where they spent years 7 to 11. Sometimes they go to a separate college, often called a 'Sixth Form College', where the regime feels less like school and more like university. During those two years they take their 'A Level' Examinations ('Advanced Level') on a much narrower curriculum than GCSE. Typically they will take only 3 or 4 subjects. The results of these A Levels are of crucial importance when it comes to gaining University entrance. The most prestigious universities often demanding 3 A-star grades. (Some local areas operate a 'three-tier system' of primary, middle and upper school)

In Britain, unlike in America, after age 18 the word ‘school’ ceases. Tertiary education involves going to 'University' or elsewhere. British people **never** refer to University as 'school'. It is sometimes called 'college', or 'uni' (orig. Australian slang), but mostly 'university'.  Young undergraduates aged 19-21 may feel exceedingly patronised if you speak of their going to 'school', even though some Universities have the word 'school' in the title e.g London School of Economics.

Comment: WS2, I don't where you got your information from but, children in the UK normally start school at 4. They start in a reception class which lasts for a full, school year. The next school year is from age 5 and is known as Year 1. That is how it was in my day and I am not exactly old.

Comment: WS2, Years 12 and 13 are still called Sixth Form, in general. That has not changed and is not just "sometimes". At this stage of education, people don't usually refer to a year number, like Year 12 or Year 13. They usually just say Sixth Form.

Comment: @Tristan. In the UK, school (more precisely education, since home-schooling is legal) is compulsory from age 5. Whether children get to start before their fifth birthday depends on a number of factors, the local education authority's policy for their area, the exact date when their birthday falls in relation to school term dates, and their parent's wishes. However, all children in the UK are now guaranteed a certain number of hours each week (possibly 15) of free nursery education from age 3.

Comment: @Tristan. I don't incidentally disagree that many children start school at 4 in the way you indicate. My grandson, whose birthday is in April, began in the September prior to his fifth birthday. The first year was called 'reception' so he began Year 1 when he was 5 years and 5 months old.

Comment: WS2, that explains a few things. You're obviously a lot older than I am so, things have obviously changed since your school days. Most people that I knew at primary school, started in reception at age 4. Even other children that I knew, who went to other schools.

Comment: What you described as the two remaining years in Secondary school, Years 12 and 13, are not exactly. They are the years of Sixth Form which is a different and separate thing from school. Even if people spend those years at the same secondary school where they spent years 7 to 11, they are not actually at school but, in Sixth Form.

Comment: For the benefit of user55213 and anyone else who is not British, Sixth Form is a separate stage of education between school and university.

Comment: @Tristan You are quite right. And this further emphasises how the word *school* is shunned by British teenagers. And this is why I emphasised the point by using capital letters, which were subsequently edited out to suit the style of the site.